# goto - not within scope (C#)

Tags: c#, goto

I am very new to code. Can anyone in a simple way explain why I cant use the goto statement like this, to make the code start over again? Or, how this could have been done in the correct way? And also, why I get an error message on the use of "static". 
**
"No such label "Start" within the scope of the goto statmenet"
"The modifier static is not valid for this item"

```
using System;


namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Start:

            Random numberGenerator = new Random();

            int num1 = numberGenerator.Next(1,11);
            int num2 = numberGenerator.Next(1, 4);


            Console.WriteLine("What is " + num1 + " times " + num2 + "?");


            int svar = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (svar == num1 * num2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("well done!");
            }
            else
            {
                int responseIndex = numberGenerator.Next(1, 4);

                switch (responseIndex)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Wrong, try again? [Y or N]");
                        AskUser();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("The answer was incorrect");
                        AskUser();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("You can do better than that");
                        AskUser();
                        break;
                }



                 static void AskUser() {
                    string jaellernei = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
                    if (jaellernei == "Y")
                    {
                     goto Start;
                    } else
                    {
                        return;
                    } }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *I am very new to code.* Then do not learn to use `goto`, you will never ever need to use it in c#.

Comment: @Rotem well, "never" is strong words... there are some things that you should not use habitually, but which do have genuine uses *when you know exactly why you're using it*. It it something I use maybe once a year...

Comment: @MarcGravell The way I see it, If you know enough to use `goto` without making a mess, then you know enough to ignore my advice.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, your `AskUser` method is incorrectly nested inside the other method - move it out.

Secondly: `goto` is only valid *within a single method*; you can jump around a single stack frame - you cannot jump *between* stack frames.

Thirdly: the number of times you should be using `goto`... well, it isn't ***quite*** zero, but it *asymptotically approaches zero*.

Comment: It's not necessarily incorrectly nested. C# supports local functions now, they just have to not be declared with the `static` keyword, even if they're part of a `static` method.

Comment: Why would you advise against using a language feature without providing a reason?

Comment: @Preza8 because I'm not required to tick any particular boxes when speaking? There's lots and lots of discussion on this topic trivially available, but if it makes you happier: "because it can make it *significantly* harder to understand the myriad paths that the code can take at execution, where other ways of structuring the code is clearer; leaving code readable and maintainable is a desirable trait"

Answer (score 0):

Don't use goto unless you **MUST** to ! 
and As @Marc Gravell said, it's **valid within a single method.**

Alternatively : you can make a method of the code u used in the Main method, and then call it from both, main method and the other method where you used goto statement.
Like :

```
 using System;
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program

    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             someFunction();
        }


        static void someFunction()
        {
            Random numberGenerator = new Random();

            int num1 = numberGenerator.Next(1, 11);
            int num2 = numberGenerator.Next(1, 4);


            Console.WriteLine("What is " + num1 + " times " + num2 + "?");


            int svar = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (svar == num1 * num2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("well done!");
            }
            else
            {
                int responseIndex = numberGenerator.Next(1, 4);

                switch (responseIndex)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Wrong, try again? [Y or N]");
                        AskUser();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("The answer was incorrect");
                        AskUser();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("You can do better than that");
                        AskUser();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        static void AskUser()
        {
            string jaellernei = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            if (jaellernei == "Y")
            {
                someFunction();
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you advise against using a language feature without providing a reason?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it  like this

```
public static Random randd = new Random();
public static void FlachCards()
{
Start:

    if (AskAUser() == "Y")
    {
        goto Start;
    }

}
public static String AskAUser()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Y to play again");
    return Console.ReadLine();
}
```